# bottstrap navbar

Tags: bootstrap

Почему не работает кнопка при уменьшении экрана.
Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>


<div class="conteiner">

  <div class="row">
  <h1>название сайта</h1>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="contentiner">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">


        </button>
          <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">название компании</a>-->

        </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">пункт-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-4</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="conteiner-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-md visible-lg">


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все работает. Проверьте подключение jquery и bootstrap.js + исправьте у себя contEiner на contAiner:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
  <h1>название сайта</h1>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
        </button>
          <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">название компании</a>-->

        </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">пункт-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт-4</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-md visible-lg">


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```